# Eclipse preferences removed on Eclipse restart

Tags: eclipse

I have been trying to change my information popup color (popup that appears when hovering a method, class...) because it looks like this [Information popup color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YyC8B.png).

I have tried to change those colors under Preferences tab and it works until I restart my eclipse, then it just comes back to that default color (the one in the first image).

After that, I have tried to make my user setup file from Oomph remember some colors. [User Setup file from Oomph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JpBV.png)

Everytime I open Eclipse it gets default color tho.
I am using DevStyle for Eclipse. [DevStyle Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/asTsL.png). I have tried to check the "Allow Oomph to track & set theming preferences button" but everytime I close the Preferences popup it gets unchecked again. The first time, it added the "includeThemingInOomph = true" preference in Oomph User Setup but it appears to do nothing.

I may be doing something wrong so every feedback is appreciated. Excuse me if there's a similar question but I haven't find the solution yet. First question on StackOverFlow also.

Answer (score 0):

After some months struggling with this, I've found a solution. Under Preferences -> General -> Appearance -> Color and Fonts -> **Java** -> **Javadoc background**
Changing this property and recording it in Oomph makes my popup always get the color I want. It is weird how the color was changed with "Information background color" in "Basic" but this seems to be the solution.